# flipping multiple images javascript

Tags: javascript, flip, flippy

I want to flip multiple images using javascript .I have 4 images , can i flip them all at the same time so it gives nice effect . I have used the flippy plugin and it works ok with one image .

any suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried. Preferably as a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

i think something like

```
$('.myImageClass').each(function(){
  $(this).flippy({
   //... options
  });
});
```

should work.

You also might want to take a look at jQuery transit:
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: thanks but that code didnt work . it only flip the first one and second one didnt .